# How to set up a confusion matrix with tensorflow 2.3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to set up a confusion matrix with tensorflow 2.3 This is the error i'm getting

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-29e008512d27> in <module>
      8 y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
      9 print('Confusion Matrix')
---> 10 print(confusion_matrix(class_names, y_pred))
     11 print('Classification Report')
     12 target_names = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Horse']

in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight)
    251 
    252     """
--> 253     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    254     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
    255         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)



in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
         69     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     70     """
---> 71     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     72     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     73     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    203     if len(uniques) > 1:
    204         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 205                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    206 
    207 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 360]
```

Here is the code To look at the confusion matrix code go to the very end but other then that this is all that is in the code. I don't know how to fix this error so anything can help

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Input

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Softmax
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy as sp 
from scipy import signal
from scipy.signal import chirp
import numpy.fft
from numpy.fft import fft as rf
import random
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.model_selection as model_selection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Input

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Softmax
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy as sp 
from scipy import signal
from scipy.signal import chirp
import numpy.fft
from numpy.fft import fft as rf
import random
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.model_selection as model_selection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import brier_score_loss
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import brier_score_loss
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from PIL import Image
import imageio as io 
import glob
from matplotlib import image

  
import h5py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Activation, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
   

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Concatenate, \
         MaxPool2D, GlobalAvgPool2D, Activation

def squeezenet(input_shape, n_classes):
  
  def fire(x, fs, fe):
    s = Conv2D(fs, 1, activation='relu')(x)
    e1 = Conv2D(fe, 1, activation='relu')(s)
    e3 = Conv2D(fe, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(s)
    output = Concatenate()([e1, e3])
    return output
  
  
  input = Input(input_shape)
  
  x = Conv2D(96, 7, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(input)
  x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = fire(x, 16, 64)
  x = fire(x, 16, 64)
  x = fire(x, 32, 128)
  x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = fire(x, 32, 128)
  x = fire(x, 48, 192)
  x = fire(x, 48, 192)
  x = fire(x, 64, 256)
  x = fire(x, 64, 256)
  x = MaxPool2D(3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    
  x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    
  x = Conv2D(n_classes, 1)(x)
  x = GlobalAvgPool2D()(x)
  x = Flatten()(x)
  
  output = Activation('softmax')(x)
  
  model = Model(input, output)
  return model

import pathlib
import PIL

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


data_dir = os.path.join("The directory before the join","the oin directory")

data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.png')))
print(image_count)

rect = list(data_dir.glob('Rect/*'))
PIL.Image.open(str(rect[1]))


batch_size = 32
img_height = 227
img_width = 227

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.1,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.1,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

normalization_layer = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image)) 

from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


model = squeezenet((227,227,3),2)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=0.0002, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(
optimizer=sgd, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=100)



acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss=history.history['loss']
val_loss=history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(100) #range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']

loss=history.history['loss']
val_loss=history.history['val_loss']

epochs_range = range(100) #range(epochs)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()



#supply a imafe to classifer to get an image out 
#calculate the confusion matrix manualy 

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix


Y_pred = model.predict_generator(val_ds, 720 // 32+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(class_names, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Horse']
print(classification_report(class_names, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

The code in question is meant to be a squeezenet implementation in python and what i'm trying to do is see if the accuracy i achieved in matlab is achievable in python.

Comment: Can you update your question with shape of `class_names` and `y_pred`? Along with some values.

Comment: The shape of class names is 1 by 3 and the y_pred is (360,) So now why is y pred (360,)

Comment: Add a standalone code example that uses generated data that reproduces this error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I added the code i think

Comment: Add a code which I can run on my machine and get the error you got. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information.

Comment: The code shown above will recreate the problem I can add the parts that get the image and all my imports if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Also I edited the code to add any of the missing pieces so assuming you download a dataset with 3 classes and run this code you should see my error